# What are reasons for a bad allocation exception

Tags: c++, memory-management, windows-10, c++14, heap-memory

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) says that std::bad_alloc exception is thrown on failure to allocated storage.

What are the steps that for example Windwos 10 does to allocated heap storage for a C++ application? Any Documentation on this would be helpful.

Does this mean std::bad_alloc is thrown when;

- The process does not have the required contiguous virtual address space to allocate storage.
- The operating system does not have required contiguous physical memory space to allocate storage.
- Both or neither?

Comment: Could be either.  It could also happen for other reasons (e.g. because a bug has corrupted your heap's internal data structures in such a way that the memory-allocation algorithm is unable to function).  `bad_alloc` is just a catch-all for anything that caused a memory allocation to fail.

Comment: That means that other processes running on the OS might cause "my" application to get a bad_alloc due to less available physical memory or more fragment physical memory.